# Trigonometry: Law of Sines

Tags: trigonometry

How can this be solved using law of sines? I get a different answer then when I solve it using law of cosines..

[image]

Comment: How have you applied sine law ?

Comment: I tried: sin65/5=siny/4. So sin(-1)x(4sin65/5) = 46.47. Then 180-46.47-65=68.53 for the angle opposite a. So, a/sin68.53=5/sin65. Thf, a=5sin68.53/sin65 = 5.13 Is that right?

Comment: That is correct, @jaykirby ....of course, being $\,y\,$ the angle between the side $\,a\,$ and $\,5\,$ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\theta$ be the angle opposite $4$. Then we have 
$$\frac{\sin\theta}{4}=\frac{\sin(65^\circ)}{5}.$$
Calculation shows that $\theta$ is about $46.47$ degrees, or $180^\circ$ minus that. The second is impossible, it would make the angle sum greater than $180^\circ$.

Now we can find the third angle by subtraction, and use the Sine Law again to find $a$.

Comment: Correct, I follow what you've done. So then the remaining angle, the one opposite a is 68.53. So, a/sin68.53=5/sin65. Thf, a=5sin68.53/sin65 = 5.13 Is that right?

Comment: Yes, I get the same thing.

Comment: Great. But then when I try solving for a using cosine rule, I get a different answer, 3.96. Could you please demonstrate how you would solve using cosine rule?

Comment: $a^2+16-8a\cos(65^\circ)=25$. We get a quadratic equation in $a$, solve. There will be two roots. Only one will be correct.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{5}{\sin 65} = \frac{4}{\sin (\text{ angle between 5 and a})}$
which gets you that angle, or two possible angles,
call them $t$ and $180-t$.

For each of these angles,
that gets you the third angle
$(180-65-that)$,
and the law of sines
gets you $a$.

Answer (score 1):

You're in the right path, just check your calculator is defined on *degrees* and not on *radians* or *gradians*:

$$\frac{\sin65^\circ}5=\frac{\sin y}4\implies \sin y=\frac45\sin65^\circ=46.47^\circ$$

and thus you are right.

Comment: So then to find a, we find the angle opposite a by subtraction and use the sine rule again. I get a=5.13, do you?

Comment: Nop. You simply substract the sum from $\,180^\circ\;$: $$180^\circ-(65^\circ+46.47^\circ)=68.53^\circ$$

Comment: In short:I wouldn't have done anything different from what you did. If somewhere is written down another result then that is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I got that I meant the value of the side length a.

Comment: How would you solve using cosine rule? Because I get a totally different answer solving for side length of a when I use that.

Comment: Oh, I see ( try to use LaTeX to write more clearly mathematics. Directions in the FAQ section): Well, after you got the last angle's value then once again, as you mentioned, the law of sines: $$\frac a{\sin68.53^\circ}=\frac5{\sin65^circ}\implies a=\frac{5\sin68.53^\circ}{\sin65^\circ}=5.13$$

Comment: Yes, that's what I got. How about using cosine rule for the same problem?

Comment: This is already too long. Try to accept one of the answers to this particular problem and perhaps open a new thread, @jaykirby

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to using latex so please excuse the displayed equations. The underlying mathematics should be accurate. Feel free to correct it if you know how.

The interior sum of angles of a triangle equal $180^\circ$. Therefore we can use [Law of Sines][1] to find $\angle A$ opposite a by deduction.

Let B be the angle opposite 4 and C=$65^\circ$. Then we have c=5.

$$\frac a{\sin A^ \circ}=\frac b{\sin B^\circ}=\frac c{\sin C^\circ}$$
$$\frac b{\sin B^\circ}=\frac c{\sin C^\circ}$$
$$\frac 4{\sin B^\circ}=\frac 5{\sin 65^\circ}$$
$$\frac 1{\sin B^\circ}=\frac 5{4\sin 65^\circ}$$
$${\sin B^\circ}=\frac {4\sin 65^\circ}5$$
$$B^\circ=\sin^{-1} ({\frac {4\sin 65^\circ}5})$$
$B=46.47269373^\circ$

Now we can find the third angle by [Sum of Angles of triangle][1] = $180^\circ$

$$180^\circ=A+B+C$$
$$180^\circ-(A+C)=B$$
$$B=68.53^\circ$$

Now you can use either [law of cosines] or [law of sines] to find $a$

Law of Cosines states:
$$a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos A^\circ$$
$$a=\sqrt{b^2+c^2-2bc\cos A^\circ}$$
$$a=\sqrt{5^2+4^2-2(5x4)\cos 68.53^\circ}$$
$$a=4.91$$