# Trigonometry: Law of Cosines

Tags: trigonometry

How to solve using rule of cosines? I can solve using law of sines but trying to check using rule of cosines is tripping me up, can anyone help clear things up?

[image: []

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LawofCosines.html or http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/cosine.shtml

Comment: any simpler explanations?

Comment: It's polite to [post links to earlier questions of yours that are relevant](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/430561/264).

Comment: Sorry, I was told to start a new thread, last question I was trying to solve with law of sines.

Comment: @jaykirby, cosine law is the best option when supplied with only one angle & any two sides. Actually, the angle $65^\circ$ does not have a known nice expression for cosine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By writing down the law of cosines for this situation, we have
$$ 5^2=a^2+4^2-2\cdot a\cdot 4\cdot \cos 65^\circ$$
i.e.
$$ a^2-3.3809 a-9\approx 0.$$
That is a quadratic in $a$, hence you'll find two solutions, but one will be negative.

Answer (score 1):

Get the angles as before:

$$65\,,\,46.47\,,\,68.53$$

and now the law of cosines:

$$a^2=5^2+4^2-2\cdot4\cdot5\cos 68.53^\circ=25.36\implies a=5.13$$

Comment: why shall we recommend finding all the three angles when one is sufficient?

Comment: I really don't why should we: I only pointed out that he already did part of this question in another thread and he can use that.

Comment: Wasn't the question on how to solve the triangle from scratch, using the law of cosines, as a check on the original solution thru multiple law of sines applications?

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to using latex so please excuse the displayed equations. The underlying mathematics should be accurate. Feel free to correct it if you know how.

The interior sum of angles of a triangle equal $180^\circ$. Therefore we can use [Law of Sines][1] to find $\angle A$ opposite a by deduction.

Let B be the angle opposite 4 and C=$65^\circ$. Then we have c=5.

$$\frac a{\sin A^ \circ}=\frac b{\sin B^\circ}=\frac c{\sin C^\circ}$$
$$\frac b{\sin B^\circ}=\frac c{\sin C^\circ}$$
$$\frac 4{\sin B^\circ}=\frac 5{\sin 65^\circ}$$
$$\frac 1{\sin B^\circ}=\frac 5{4\sin 65^\circ}$$
$${\sin B^\circ}=\frac {4\sin 65^\circ}5$$
$$B^\circ=\sin^{-1} ({\frac {4\sin 65^\circ}5})$$
$$B=46.47269373^\circ$$

Now we can find the third angle by [Sum of Angles of triangle][1] = $180^\circ$

$$180^\circ=A+B+C$$
$$180^\circ-(A+C)=B$$
$$B=68.53^\circ$$

Now you can use either [law of cosines] or [law of sines] to find $a$

Law of Cosines states:
$$a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos A^\circ$$
$$a=\sqrt{b^2+c^2-2bc\cos A^\circ}$$
$$a=\sqrt{5^2+4^2-2(5x4)\cos 68.53^\circ}$$
$$a=4.91$$